# agora.io Android SDK: how to adjust microphone volume

Tags: android, agora.io

I've integrated the Agora android SDK into my app. In the video chat channel, some of my testing android devices have very low microphone volume (eg, Pixel 2 / 2 XL), is there a way to always set the microphone volume to the highest?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the following guide on how to control the volume: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/volume_android?platform=Android.

In particular, to control the recording volume, you will need to do the following:

```
int volume = 200;
// Sets the volume of the recorded signal.
rtcEngine.adjustRecordingSignalVolume(volume);
```

400 is the highest possible value for the volume.